# how get a WiFi disconnect event using wpa_cli when wifi is disconnected

Tags: embedded-linux, wpa-supplicant

i'm Working on a embedded Linux system. I need to connect to new WiFi when the existing WiFi disconnects. I can use a loop with a fixed sleep time and see if the wifi is connected or not, but it seems inefficient.
Can anyone suggest a way that wpa_cli can be started as a daemon that fires an event when WiFi is disconnected.

Thanks in advance.
Sundeep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the control socket that wpa_supplicant exposes to allow external applications to control it.docs are [here](http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html). You try it out on wpa_cli, eg: run following commmand in wpa_cli **scan** and **scan_results**. When you connect to the socket you get all the events like connection,disconection etc. These events are described in the docs